# Intellij idea how to deploy project with all resources

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a web application project and when I try to deploy my project to server I can't see my properties files(i18n). How can I deploy my project with all resources?

**EDIT:** For example I have some classes and properties files under my src folder; src/login/login.properties and src/login/login.class. When I build and deploy this project I can't see my properties files.

Comment: Could you provide more details about what's not working? What do you mean by "I can't see my properties files"? What kind of project/server is it? How do you deploy your app?

Comment: Your project structure is non-standard. If you use maven and follow the default project structure you will get much further. Simply following the default project structure alone will be of great benefit, but going fully to maven will make your life a lot easier. Maven has a plugin for building war files, and IntelliJ understands maven configuration (pom) files.